# Ionic/Angular ui-router: Count parent state and its child as one state while navigating back

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angular-ui-router

My abstract state is a frame with tabs that loads in the lower section a template depending on the active tab. The layout is similar to this:

[image]

The **problem** is that when I navigate back it also navigates through the tabs, instead of going to the previous state. How can I prevent this behaviour?

This is the template of my parent state

```
<ion-tabs>
  <ion-tab ui-sref="home.user.details">
  </ion-tab>
  <ion-tab ui-sref="home.user.followers">
  </ion-tab>
</ion-tabs>
<ion-nav-view class="inner-view"></ion-nav-view>
```

And this is my `ui-router` configuration

```
.state('home.user', {
  url: '/user/:id',
  abstract: false,
  cache: true,
  template: '<user></user>',
  resolve: {
    id: function($stateParams) {
      return $stateParams.id;
    }
  }
})
.state('home.user.details', {
  url: '/details',
  templateUrl: 'template/user.details.html'
})

.state('home.user.followers', {
  url: '/followers',
  templateUrl: 'template/user.followers.html'
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do this when the hardware backbutton is used you could do it with Ionic's `onHardwareBackButton` feature by manually setting the state where it should navigate to like this:

```
$ionicPlatform.onHardwareBackButton(onBackButton);

function onBackButton(e) {
  $state.go('home.user');
}
```

You can register the above on the tab states and then remove it with `offHardwareBackButton` when the wanted behaviour changes like this:

```
$ionicPlatform.offHardwareBackButton(onBackButton);
```

I didn't see a back button but if you do have/want one replace it with a self made on and make it go to the parent state with something like this:

HTML:

```
<button class="button" ng-click="goToHome()">
  <i class="icon ion-android-arrow-back"></i>
</button>
```

Controller:

```
$scope.goToHome = function() {
  $state.go('home.user');
};
```

Comment: Hi @thepio, thanks for your help. I've tried this approach but I don't know how to get the state I want to navigate to since my parent state represents a user profile and I can have a chain of states like this `home > user1 > user2` that my back button should navigate through. I've tried using `$stateParams` to pass the previous view to my `user` but it always passes `home`.

Comment: Can't you just use `$state.go('home.user', {id: $stateParams.id});`? Or you could store the previous state user id somewhere and use it if you want to go one step back. This is my assumption if I understood you correctly.

Comment: The `id` passed as parameter is the id of the user I want to show. Anyway, I've been able to make it work using `ui-sref="home.user.basics({id: userID, prev: $ionicHistory.currentView()})"` and using `$state.go(prev.stateName, prev.stateParams)`. You last comment helped me going in this direction. Thanks

Comment: Ok, cool that you got it working! Glad I could help you to the right direction :)